# Button not Rendering when returning to page

Tags: visualforce, rendered

I have a visualforce page with two buttons.  When I navigate off the page and then return to the page, the Edit button is not visible.  If I refresh the page, the Edit button becomes visible.  The View button has the same attributes and does not disappear.  The buttons are the same with the exception of the action they call.

Any ideas on why the edit button would not display and the view would?

Thanks!

Fred

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!ieList}" var="ie" >
            <apex:column headerValue="Edit">
                <apex:commandButton value="Edit" action="{!Edit}" reRender="EntirePage1"  status="overlayStatus" immediate="True">
                    <apex:param name="ieId" value="{!ie.Id}" assignTo="{!ieId}"/>
                 </apex:commandButton>
            </apex:column>

            <apex:column headerValue="View">
                <apex:commandButton value="View" action="{!View}" reRender="EntirePage1"  status="overlayStatus" immediate="True">
                    <apex:param name="ieId" value="{!ie.Id}" assignTo="{!ieId}"/>
                 </apex:commandButton>
            </apex:column>

                <apex:column headerValue="Delete">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!ie.Delete__c}" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Employee" styleclass="employeename">
                  <apex:outputField value="{!ie.Employee__c}" />                    
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Confirm Mismatch AM"><apex:outputField value="{!ie.Confirm_Mismatch_AM__c}" /></apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Covered By">
                    <apex:outputField value="{!ie.Covered_By__c}" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Employee Manager"><apex:outputField value="{!ie.Employee_Manager__c}" /></apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Lock Incented Manager"><apex:outputField value="{!ie.Lock_Incented_Manager__c}" /></apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Confirm Mismatch Manager"><apex:outputField value="{!ie.Confirm_Mismatch_Manager__c}" /></apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Member Credit Type"><apex:inputField value="{!ie.Member_Credit_Type__c}" /></apex:column>                                        
                <apex:column headerValue="Member Lock In"><apex:inputField value="{!ie.Member_Lock_In__c}" /></apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Member Credit Percentage"><apex:inputField value="{!ie.Member_Credit_Percentage__c}" /></apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Current Enrollment Date"><apex:outputField value="{!ie.Current_Enrollment_Date__c}" /></apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Member Credit"><apex:outputField value="{!ie.Member_Credit__c}" /></apex:column>

           </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not seeing the `Edit` `commandButton` because you are using the standard `Edit` `actionMethod` from `standard controller`. And `Edit` and `Delete` standard `actionMethods` works only when you have an `ID` specified in the `URL`. This is because, without `ID` it would not have which record to `edit` or `delete`. That is the reason, these buttons does not appear without ID.

So, when you are initially on the page, you would be seeing the `Edit` button because you must be having the `ID` in the `URL` and then when you navigate off and return back to the page, your `ID` from the URL must have been removed, hence `Edit` button disappears.

So to fix this issue, from wherever you are navigating to this `visualforce` page, you should make sure that you always pass the record's `ID` in `URL`.

URL when navigating to your visualforce page should be :

> yourdomain.visual.force.com/apex/yourpageName?id=recordId

Comment: Thank you so much for our response!! I actually thought I was using a custom action on the button but using the standard edit in the button was causing me the issue.  Updating the name of my custom method fixed the issue.  Thank you so much for your help!!!!

Comment: Glad to help you